# Does NRND spell the end for a niche product?

Tags: components

I'm just wondering about this. Luckily I'm not faced with the problem myself.

If I design a product around a specific MCU and have that produced in a niche market, selling maybe a few hundred every year (maximum), would that MCU going NRND (not recommended for new designs) affect me badly? I can imagine I'd have to start a redesign around another chip... how long would I have to do this? Why does a chip go NRND anyway? Is it due to insufficient demand? What if I were a bigger company and just had an order for 10,000 units - would the manufacturer reconsider their decision?

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm worrying about this, because I'd like the same design to work for as long as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NRND could be translated as End of Life is coming.

Could just be a 'better' part exists.

Time to look at manufacturers roadmap.

NRND is the fist step to Last time buy, then End of life.

**It will normally take years to go to last time buy.**

You'll be able to buy chips from scalpers for years after that.

If you don't buy millions, generally manufacturers ignore you.

Stick with industrial, long lifespan parts. Consumer parts turn over fast.

Comment: Consumer parts can be the bane of an embedded product.

Answer (score 3):

Companies try their best to keep products around as long as they can. However, every product has cost associated with it in order to just keep it as a separate SKU. Usually an end of life product either has a replacement that can replace the old component with no changes needed by you. If they haven't done this then they probably have very few orders for that item and are just selling off all remaining stock.

10,000 units probably isn't enough for a company to go back on their decision. There is always a chance for negotiation, but financially they have already decided they are better off selling other components.